# Pressing a button in the list of JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a list of JQM,  and a button for each instance on a list.

When click on the button I call to function ...

```
function xxx()
{
    alert ('click on me!! :]');
}
```

Clicking on the button Not triggering the function, why?

Look at the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hodaya/nR369/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind the `xxx` function to the click event of the `newLI` DOM element you should either use the `newLI.onclick=xxx;` or better yet use jQuery to do the binding with `$(newLI).click(xxx);`

Comment: I do not want to run the function by clicking on the list, I want to run it by clicking on the button that in the list.

Comment: It is not .. Because when click on a list I have another function Run

Comment: And the function in http://jsfiddle.net/S2rFk/  does not always work, there are clicks that lead to nothing.

Comment: Then I guess I do not understand your question: the fiddle provides an example of triggering a function based on a click on the button of a list item. If that was not your question, could you clarify what you are trying to attain ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem is resolved:

Pressing the button did not work because:

to each button on the list was the same id ,In the moment I added a unique name for each of the buttons, it worked.

Here the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Local.length; i++) {
     newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="to.html" data-transition="slide" dir="rtl" onclick="YYY();" >' + 
                       '<p>...'</p>' +
                       '<a  id="btnClearOneBookmark' + i + '" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b"></a>' +
                      ' </a>';

        $("#btnClearOneBookmark" + i).click(function () { xxx(); });
}
```

Comment: Highly disappointing that you would copy paste the answer I provided you with in the fiddle and claim it as your own

Comment: You brought code worked correctly, but have not explained yourself that all id have to give a unique name, and for that reason it does not work,  I got it on my own, but in any case thanks for the help, I'll get your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#mybutton").on('click',function() {
var ul = document.getElementById("bookMarkMenu");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
    console.log(i)
        newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="to.html"  data-transition="slide" dir="rtl"><p>...</p>' +'<a id="btnClearOneBookmark" data-theme="b" data-role = "button"></a></a>';
    newLI.setAttribute('data-theme', 'c');
    newLI.setAttribute('onclick', 'DisplayBookMark()');
    ul.appendChild(newLI);
    $('ul').listview('refresh');
} 
});

$("#btnClearOneBookmark").live('click',function() {
    alert("click on me!! :]");
});
```